# making slideshow image black and white

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, caroufredsel

I am using slideshow from http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/

html code is like this

```
<div id="wrapper1">
            <div id="carousel">
                <img src="images/slider1.jpg" alt="building1" width="990" height="620" />
                <img src="images/slider2.jpg" alt="building2" width="990" height="620" />
                <img src="images/slider3.jpg" alt="building3" width="990" height="620" />
                <img src="images/slider4.jpg" alt="building4" width="990" height="620" />

            </div>
            <a href="#" id="prev" title="Show previous"> </a>
            <a href="#" id="next" title="Show next"> </a>
            <div id="pager"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS is like this

```
 <style type="text/css">



            #wrapper1 {
                background-color: #fff;
                width: 100%;
                height: 620px;
                margin-top: -225px;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 0;
            }
            #carousel img {
                display: block;
                float: left;
            }

            #prev, #next {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
                display: block;
                height: 620px;
                width: 50%;
                top: 0;
                position: absolute;


            }

            #prev:hover, #next:hover {
                background-color: #fff;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);

            }
            #prev {
                left: -495px;
            }
            #next {
                right: -495px;
            }

        </style>
```

and script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                    width: '100%',
                    items: {
                        visible: 3,
                        start: -1
                    },
                    scroll: {
                        items: 1,
                        duration: 1000,
                        timeoutDuration: 3000
                    },
                    prev: '#prev',
                    next: '#next',
                    pagination: {
                        container: '#pager',
                        deviation: 1
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

It is working properly. But i want to make partial previous and next images are in black and white, when mouse over it should turn normal.

Something like this

http://www.viyahome.com/

I am not getting how to do it.

I applied grayscale 100%, but it doesn't work.

Please suggest me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use grayscale. im not sure but you can try out by making following changes in the css code.

```
#prev, #next {

                display: block;
                height: 620px;
                width: 50%;
                top: 0;
                position: absolute;
// add this

                filter: grayscale(100%);
                -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
               filter: gray;  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
              -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */

            }

            #prev:hover, #next:hover {
               /* background-color: #fff;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);*/
                filter: grayscale(0%);
                -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
                filter: none;
            }
```

check out whether it works.

Comment: I tried, But it doesn't works :(. images are showing as it is :(

Comment: try some other variations of grayscale,,, it can be done by grayscale only, check out the link how they have done it,, http://james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale/

Comment: try some other variations of grayscale,,, it can be done by grayscale only, check out the link how they have done it,, james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale

Answer (score 0):

Try this, do the following changes.
add following function to your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $("#carousel").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() { 
        $("#carousel").children().css("-webkit-filter","");
        $($("#carousel").children()[0]).css("-webkit-filter","grayscale(100%)");
        $($("#carousel").children()[2]).css("-webkit-filter","grayscale(100%)");
    });

    $("#prev").mouseenter(function(){
        $($("#carousel").children()[0]).css("-webkit-filter","");
    });

    $("#next").mouseenter(function(){
        $($("#carousel").children()[2]).css("-webkit-filter","");
    });


    $("#prev").mouseleave(function(){
        $($("#carousel").children()[0]).css("-webkit-filter","grayscale(100%)");
    });

    $("#next").mouseleave(function(){
        $($("#carousel").children()[2]).css("-webkit-filter","grayscale(100%)");
    });

});
```

Change only these css changes as well

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #prev, #next {
        /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);*/
        display: block;
        height: 450px;
        width: 50%;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #prev:hover, #next:hover {
        /*background-color: #fff;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);*/
    }
</script>
```

This is working fine for Google chrome. In order to work for other browsers add followings to all necessary places

```
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Explanation: You try to add gray scale filters to the prev and next elements. but we have to think about how to apply these style changes to images. So what I did here is that listen the DOM tree changes and add css rules dynamically for left and right images.